# How to Save My RSS Feed in a Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting an RSS feed from a site, but if there is no internet connection, the user can't read the RSS information that the phone has already downloaded. So I would like to store them in a database in order to read them even when the mobile is not connected with Wifi/3G. Do you have any idea how to do it? Any tutorials are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Depends, I wouldn't recommend storing it in a database unless you want absolutely fast querying. Why don't you just serialize the object?

Answer (score 0):

save the RSS response string as a file in internal storage, or in `SharedPreferences`.  then simply re-parse the RSS when you want to view.  saving it in a database is too much work for all this.